# Is it possible to change product attribute type in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento-2.1.2

I created one attribute programmatically and set input type of attribute Multi Select.

Now I want to change that attribute input type **Multi Select** to **Dropdown**.

Is it possible? If yes than how can I change that

Answer (score 7):

Use below code of upgradeData:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
       $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }


    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    { 
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.2', '<')) {

            $entityType = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

            $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'mytest', 'frontend_input','select', null);
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'mytest', 'used_in_product_listing' , true, null);


        }
    }
}
```

Change `mytest` with your attribute code in above code.If you have any issue please let me know.

Comment: After changing product attribute, it will be assign the product same or not.

Answer (score 2):

Below code updates "attribute_name" attribute type to drop down.

```
           $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
                 \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                 'attribute_name',    
                 'frontend_input',
                 'select'
             );

         $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
                 \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                 'attribute_name',    
                 'source_model',
                 'Modulenamespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Options'
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Please use patch file instead of UpgradeData.php**

> **I convert my attribute to price input type**

**app/code/Vendorname/ModuleName/Setup/Patch/Data**

**UpdateProductAttribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class UpdateProductAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $entityType = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

        // Update you_attr_code Attribute
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'frontend_input', 'price', null);

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'backend_model', 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price');

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'attribute_model', 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $entityType = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

        // Revert you_attr_code Attribute
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'frontend_input', 'text', null);

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'backend_model', null);

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'attribute_model', null);


        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**For More**: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/patches/

Answer (score 0):

Run `upgradeData` script by your existing "Attribute Code" as a identifier.

I have updated input type for `test_attribute6` as a identifier for existing attribute as described below.

```
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'test_attribute6',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => 'dropdown',
            'frontend' => 'dropdown',
            'label' => 'Test Attribute6',
            'input' => 'dropdown',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```