# Magento 2 Catalog Input Type for Store Owner from Visual Swatch to Dropdown programatically

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav-attributes

How can I change Catalog Input Type for Store Owner from Visual Swatch to Dropdown in Magento 2 programmatically

```
$eavSetup->updateAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'size', 'swatch_input_type', 'dropdown');
```

not working

Comment: try these below ways   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147282/is-it-possible-to-change-product-attribute-type-in-magento-2

Comment: no, it does not working, already tried. maybe in work for text types. but not for swatch